# How can we use Deferred DAG assignment in airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to Apache airflow and working with DAG. y code is given below.

In the input json i have a parameter named as 'sports_category'. if its value is 'football' then football_players task need to run if its value is cricket then 'cricket_players' task runs.

```
import airflow

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.databricks_operator import DatabricksSubmitRunOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 6, 23)
}

dag = DAG('PLAYERS_DETAILS',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None,max_active_runs=5) 

football_players = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='football_players',
    databricks_conn_id='football_players_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': {{ jar path }}
        }        
        ],
        databricks_retry_limit = 3,
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'football class name1',
        'parameters' : [
            'json ={{ dag_run.conf.json }}'     
        ]
    }
)

cricket_players = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
    task_id='cricket_players',
    databricks_conn_id='cricket_players_details',
    existing_cluster_id='{{ dag_run.conf.clusterId }}',
    libraries= [
        {
        'jar': {{ jar path }}
        }        
        ],
        databricks_retry_limit = 3,
    spark_jar_task={
        'main_class_name': 'cricket class name2',
        'parameters' : [
            'json ={{ dag_run.conf.json }}'     
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using BranchPythonOperator which takes one function as an argument and return which TASK need to be run next in the flow based on the logic written inside the function.

Refer [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch#branching) for documentation and [here](https://medium.com/@guillaume_payen/use-conditional-tasks-with-apache-airflow-98bab35f1846) for an example dag.

Let me know your response!